# What is the subject in “Trop d'inégalités nuit à la croissance”?

Tags: pronoms, sujet

1. Is it correct to consider *trop d'inégalités* as a third-person subject? I guess it might be a *syllepse*...
2. Then why can I say

   > Jean, il est grand.

   and not

   > Trop d'inégalités, il n'est pas souhaitable.

   ?
3. Would you have examples of similar structures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Indeed, “trop d'inégalités” is the subject of the verb “nuire”.
2. You can form a similar sentence with a dislocated subject, but the adequate pronoun is *ce* in this case (and *cela* or *ça* for most other verbs) :

   > Trop d'inégalités, *ce* n'est pas souhaitable.
3. If your question is about atypical subjects, you may notice that infinitive clauses can also be used as subjects:

   > Nourrir les pigeons a été interdit par arrêté municipal.
   >   Nourrir les pigeons, c'est interdit.